# Android Studio Java EditText Contains Words

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

For Android Studio: 
I would like to check if words are typed in 'edit text'. If so, then I will return a 'text view'.

I am having trouble figuring out the exact code to type.

For example, this is what I have:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < suiWords.length; i++) {
    if (editPost.contains(suiWords[i])) {
       msgHotline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       break;
       }
    }
```

"contains" is giving me an error message, so I know that is not the right code to use.

Does anyone know what command I need to use to check whether or not a certain word is typed?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Notes:

- I already tried searching Google + Stack Overflow for an answer and no luck. If you found the link, please kindly post it here.
- I am still a student.

Comment: What is editPost? What is suiWords? Please post more of your code to help us undestand

Comment: editPost, suiWords, and msgHotline are id names.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean with id names? Which type are suiWords and editPost?

Comment: 'cannot resolve method contains(java.lang.String)'

Comment: editPost = EditText, suiWords = String of array, and msgHotline = TextView in my xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `editPost.getText().toString().equals(suiWords[i])`

Comment: @Sugarcoder You are welcome. If you find my answer useful please accept it as the Answer and vote it up.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot vote it up because not enough reputation, but I accepted it. Have a nice day/evening. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < suiWords.length; i++) {
    if (editPost.getText().toString().contains(suiWords[i])) {
       msgHotline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check, whether your EditText value contains a specific value, Then you can use these line of code.
`editText.getText().toString().contains("valueToCheck")`